# What is a DataVO pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

While looking at some open source code to learn more about J2EE, I came across classes (or packages) named DataVO. In the code I looked at, this was simply serialized XML used by other classes.

What is the DataVO pattern exactly? and how does it differ from Data access object or Data transfer object?

Thanks!

Comment: 'VO' stands for 'Value Object'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a while DTO and VO were the same thing.  Basically a record structure with getters and setters, no real objectness to it.